# Is it possible to create an ACL (Acces Control List) for OGC SOS (Sensor Observation Service) protocols

Tags: ogc, sos

What alternatives exist to create an ACL (Acces Control List) for OGC SOS (Sensor Observation Service) protocol?

My goal is enable only some resource (Sensors, procedures or offerings) at some users.

The only two solutions found are:

•   The 52n Web Enforcement Service (WSS): underdeveloped, it cannot be download.

•   Geoshield: Small community, difficulty to find technical information, and 
only offer support to first version s of SOS 1.0.

Comment: The answer to most "Is it possible" questions is "Yes". Please **edit the question** to expand on what you want to accomplish, and to describe what your research has uncovered but which is not adequate for your purposes.